# Add a product subtitle in woocommerce archives pages like shop

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, advanced-custom-fields

I am a total beginner with PHP and would like to add a subtitle before the product title on the woocommerce shop page. The subtitle should be gathered from a Advanced Custom field and put in a div so I can style it.

The code i tried in functions.php puts the subtitle after the product title instead of before and does not output the value of the custom field.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_shop_loop_item_title', 'woocommerce_shop_loop_item_subtitle', 20 );
function woocommerce_shop_loop_item_subtitle() {
    global $product;
    echo '<div class="size">' . __("the_field('sizes');", "woocommerce") . '</div>';
}
```

Comment: are you expecting `the_field('sizes');` to give an output? Because currently it's just a string. Also, why are you using the `__()` translation function?

Comment: Yes, the_field('sizes'); should output the value of this custom field of the product

Comment: is `the_field()` a plugin function? Because it isn't a WordPress core function. If so, is there a `get_field()` function or alike? `the_field()` likely prints and that won't work with concatenation. You would have to write it like this: `echo '<div class="size">' . get_field('sizes')  . '</div>';` or at least get rid of the double quotes.

Comment: Or if you want to translate the value: `echo '<div class="size">' . __(get_field('sizes'), 'woocommerce') . '</div>';`

Comment: Yes it is a function from the advanced custom fields plugin. Thanks for the solution, it outputs the correct value. Now I just need to put it before the title instead of after. Any ideas?

Comment: You could try to play around with the priority of the action. (the third argument of `add_action()`) that's currently set to 20. Otherwise find a different hook that's executed before `woocommerce_shop_loop_item_title`

Comment: Ahh yes, setting the priority of the action to 2 fixed it. Thank you so much, I am super beginner and this helped a lot!

Comment: I'll form my comments into an answer. Please be kind and upvote / mark it as accepted ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How it's currently written it's just a string. Remove the double quotes.

Also use `get_field()` instead of `the_field()` because `the_field()` will print. That won't work when concatenating strings.

Change the priority of the action to determine the location of the subtitle.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_shop_loop_item_title', 'woocommerce_shop_loop_item_subtitle', 2 );
function woocommerce_shop_loop_item_subtitle() {
    global $product;
    echo '<div class="size">' . __(get_field('sizes'), 'woocommerce') . '</div>';
}
```